# Array is returning "Array" instead of the actual values of the array

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I have an array of values that I am trying to output to a string using the following code:

```
$arrayINS = explode(", ", $arraystring);
foreach ($arrayINS as &$array1INS) {
    $array1INS = "(" . $arrayINS . ", 'Some Text Here')";
}
$arrayvaluesINS = implode(', ', $arrayINS);
```

Now, let's say that the `$arraystring = 25145, 25064, 24812`. I would expect `echo $arrayvaluesINS` to be

> (25145, 'Some text here'), (25064, 'Some text here'), (24812, 'Some
>   text here')

But instead what I get is:

> (Array, 'Some text here'), (Array, 'Some text here'), (Array, 'Some
>   text here')

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$arrayINS` is the array.

```
$array1INS = "(" . $arrayINS . ", 'Some Text Here')";
```

should be

```
$array1INS = "(" . $array1INS . ", 'Some Text Here')";
```

Next time use meaningful variable name.

Comment: Actually, it should be: `$array1INS[] = "(" . $array1INS . ", 'Some Text Here')";`. ;)

Comment: Right, I have not noticed `&`. Sorry for noise.

Comment: Stoopid error! How did I not see that?! Been staring at this for 2 hours trying to solve it! Thank you, @xdazz.

Answer (score -1):

You're using $array1INS as the iteration variable in the for, but then in the next line, you use $arrayINS in the assignment (which is an Array) and overwrite what you had put in $array1INS. Try this:

```
foreach ($arrayINS as &$item) {
   $array1INS = "(" . $item . ", 'Some Text Here')";
}
```

Comment: Undefined variable `$array1INS` -1. Next time make sure you post working sample. :)

Comment: I certainly don't agree with your downvote:

$array1INS gets defined when assigning to it.

Comment: Did you actually test the link posted? it works. You downvoted my suggestion without even using common sense or knowledge of PHP to know $array1INS can't be undefined there. Anyway, this is not the place to fight, and I'm stopping here.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Reread OP's question. [Here's](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1jJ6WJ) what you actually had to do. And nobody is fighting. ;)